# HIVE decimal 2 precision

Tags: hadoop, hive

In my hive table the actual values looks as below.

```
 100
 200.345
 12.365
```

I want to have them looks like:

```
 100.00
 200.34
 12.36
```

How it can be possible?

Comment: You mean select result looks like or update the data to be that way?

Comment: based on the version of hive you are using you could use double for 2 precisions

Answer (score 1):

You should declare as **decimal(5,2)**. [Hive Decimals](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Decimalsdecimal) .

The syntax is **DECIMAL(precision, scale)**. Precision means the number of digits of this number including the digits after the dot.